# Ruby on Rails: How do I move all files from one folder to another folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

But I also need a way to rename them incase there are conflicts.

Like `if exists? then file.name = "1-"+file.name`
or something like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this works for you:

```
origin = '/test_dir'
destination = '/another_test_dir'

Dir.glob(File.join(origin, '*')).each do |file|
  if File.exists? File.join(destination, File.basename(file))
    FileUtils.move file, File.join(destination, "1-#{File.basename(file)}")
  else
    FileUtils.move file, File.join(destination, File.basename(file))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Above code works, but little mistake, You are using `if File.exists?(file)`, which is checking if file exits in origin folder/or subfolder,( which is of no use, since it was read because it already exists). You need to check if file already exists in destination folder. Because of this syntax the "else" is never getting executed. And all files are getting named like "1-filename".
Correct would be to use

```
if File.exists? File.join(destination, File.basename(file))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to run the command in the shell and deal with the response:

```
command = "mv *.* #{ new_directory }/"

response = system command
```

Dealing with existing filenames, etc. is another matter, however.